FSC exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated! in flowCore package
I'm trying to plot fcs (flow cytometry) file in r by flowCore package, but I don't know if my problem is with the package or the coding. I'll explain what I did and I'm hoping you guys can help me out here.
I first installed the package as
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("flowCore", force = TRUE)

library('flowCore')

then recieved a warning

Warning message:
package(s) not installed when version(s) same as or greater than
current; use force = TRUE to re-install: 'flowCore'

so I've wrote
BiocManager::install("flowCore", force = TRUE)


Bioconductor version 3.18 (BiocManager 1.30.23), R 4.3.3
(2024-02-29)
Installing package(s) 'flowCore'
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.18/bioc/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/flowCore_2.14.2.tgz'


Old packages: 'Hmisc', 'knitr', 'SparseM'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: a downloaded

library('flowCore')
x <- read.FCS("~/Downloads/Specimen_001_Tube_001.fcs", transformation = FALSE)

Here I started to struggle with a second warning

Warning messages:
1: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of 'FSC-A' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
2: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of 'FSC-W' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
3: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of 'SSC-A' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
4: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of 'SSC-W' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
5: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of '488 530/30-A' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
6: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of '488 530/30-H' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'
7: In readFCSdata(con, offsets, txt, transformation, which.lines, scale,  :
Some data values of '488 530/30-W' channel exceed its $PnR value 262144 and will be truncated!
To avoid truncation, either fix $PnR before generating FCS or set 'truncate_max_range = FALSE'

I tried this
x <- read.FCS("~/Downloads/Specimen_001_Tube_001.fcs", transformation = FALSE, truncate_max_range = FALSE)

but I still keep getting the same warning!!
Is something wrong with package in accordance with R version? or the problem with $PnR can be solved through a code? How can this be solved?

FCS files can have event values that exceed the specified channel range ($PnR value) and is allowed for channels with floating point data types. You can try another library such as FlowKit in Python (full disclosore, I am the author). However, I believe what you are seeing is just a warning for this case.
